# Nesting method calls

Tags: go

How can I nest methods in Go?

Let's say, I have 2 files, each in a different package.

`First file: handlers/user.go`

```
type Resolver struct {
    client *elastic.Client
    index  string
}

func (r *Resolver) CreateUser(ctx context.Context, name string) (*model.User, error) {
    u, err := services.CreateUserService(ctx, r.client, r.index, name)
    
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return u, nil
}
```

and `another file: services/user.go`

```
func CreateUserService(ctx context.Context, client *elastic.Client, index string, name string) (*model.User, error) {

    u := &model.User{
        Name:   name
    }

    //doing some other function call
    err := dao.CreateUserDAO(ctx, client, index, s)

    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return u, nil
}
```

This works fine. But I am still having to pass 2 parameters as `r.client` and `r.index`.

What I want to do, is make a call like
`services.r.CreateUserService(ctx, name)`.

This makes my code more readable and less cluttered.

But I am not sure, how to change the services package to accommodate this change.

How can I do that?

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking - what would `services.r.CreateUserService` be equivalent to? What would be the expected values for `client` and `index`?

Comment: Did you read the code snippet? If it still isn't clear, `client` and `index` are being passed inside the `Resolver` struct.

Comment: You can have a struct `service` which has `resolver` as its field. Then the method on `service` can use `resolver` inside the `createUserService` method.

Comment: @A.C it still isn't very clear to me. A simple code snippet would be really helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, try to create such a method.

```
func (r *Resolver) CreateUser(ctx context.Context, name string) (*model.User, error) {
    u, err := r.CreateUserService(ctx, name)

    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return u, nil
}

func (r *Resolver) CreateUserService(ctx context.Context, name string) (*model.User, error) {

    return services.CreateUserService(ctx, r.client, r.index, name)

}
```

But I have no idea how to call like `services.r.CreateUserService(ctx, name)` unless `services` is a class which includes a `Resolver`, that's so weird.

Comment: yeah, I understand that it is weird. 
I have an OOP background, hence was trying to figure out how to do this in Go.
What you have done, is just add another function call, and I don't think I want that.
Thanks!